# When will compile_to_c with vector types be supported?

Tags: halide

When will `compile_to_c` with vector types be supported?

I've added calling `Pipeline::compile_to_c()` at [conv_layer.cpp](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/auto_scheduler/test/auto_schedule/conv_layer.cpp):93 line for getting C code generated by halide.

```cpp
std::vector<Argument> empty_arg;
// p is defined like "Pipeline p(f_ReLU);"
p.compile_to_c("conv_layer.out.cpp", empty_arg, "f_ReLU");
```

After building `conv_layer.cpp` and then running it causes assertion error at [CodeGen_C.cpp#212](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/auto_scheduler/src/CodeGen_C.cpp#L212):

> Can't use vector types when compiling to C (yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very low priority - it would take a lot of work to make it portable, and for not much payoff. Code generated by the C backend is slower to compile and slower to run than code generated via the LLVM backends, so it's not suitable for actually getting high-performance code. I'm not entirely sure, but I believe it's slower because we can't easily express all the aliasing and alignment info in the emitted C code that we can in LLVM bitcode.